# UnitTesting and Functional Testing on Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, functional-testing

I have created an app that sends intents among multiple activities.  After doing some research I have found that the `ActivityUnitTestCase` class is designed for unit testing while the `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` is designed for functional testing.  I understand the use of methods such as `setUp()`, `tearDown()`, and `testPreConditions()`.  However I am having a little difficulty in trying to figure out what *user-defined-tests* to create in the previously mentioned classes.  I know that there are a few methods that cannot be called in certain classes.

To be more specific, if I am in **activity A** and I click a button then it calls `startActivityForResult()` which starts **activity B**.  I then send an intent back to **activity A** which is handled in the `onActivityResult()` method.  How can i test that the actual result in `onActivityResult()` is equal to the expected result?

I have been looking extensively for any kind of examples that would help clear up this confusion.  If anyone could provide any assistance i would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of thing, you would probably test the results sent to onActivityResult indirectly, by actually testing the changes made to the view by the view controller.  We use an instance of ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 coupled with the [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) library (which I can highly recommend).

```
public class AdvancedSearchActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<AdvancedSearchActivity> {

    private Solo solo;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    public void testWhenActivityLoads_shouldShowCorrectWidgets() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(solo.searchText("Location:"));
        assertTrue(solo.searchText("Map Radius:"));
        assertTrue(solo.searchButton("Search"));
    }
}
```

The ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 only specifies the base activity to start, so there's no reason you can't start other activities through the test (simulate a button click, etc) and then come back from those with the results.  We've done that here many times.  I'd avoid trying to have an integration-type test actually try to get the results from onActivityResult directly though.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea.  I will definitely try this out.  And yes am actually using Robotium.  So why is it that an integration-type test to get the result of onActivityResult directly is a bad practice?

Comment: In my opinion, with Robotium we're dealing with user experience level testing, and the looking at the results of onActivityResult is at a much lower level.  Also, I just think it'd be really hard, and require pretty invasive tests.  A lot of work for little return if you can test it another way.